# beginner-opening explorer to show folder contents

Tags: python

I've been tinkering with Python 3.66 a few days now on windows 7. Making good progress,
but I am totally stuck on how to make windows explorer open with my desired folder contents showing.

I have tried at least 7 different solutions from related questions on here but none seem to work. They all open explorer fine, but never with my Folder_selected
variable.

The explorer bit is the final line of code.
Here is the (badly coded I suspect) source:

```
#FRenum-v.04
#renumbers a folder of files to 01 onward preserving file extenders.
#Steve Shambles june 2018, my 2nd ever python program

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os
import os.path
import subprocess

#user selects directory
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()                             #stop tk window opening
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory() #open file requestor

#change dir to folder selected by user,
os.chdir (folder_selected)
#path is now the dir
path=(folder_selected)

# read user selected dir   
files = os.listdir(folder_selected)

# inc is counter to keep track of what file we are working on
inc = 1 

for file in files:
    #store file extender in string file_ext
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

    # build new filename, starting with a "0" then 
    #value of inc then add file extender
    created_file=("0"+str(inc)+ file_ext)

    #if file does not exist rename it
    if not os.path.exists(created_file):
        os.rename(file,created_file)

        #next one please, until done
        inc = inc+1 #add to counter

#open explorer showing folder of renamed files   
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"]) 

#these do not work properly, opens in c: or my docs    
#subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"+ folder_selected]) 
#subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", folder_selected])    
#subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe","folder_selected"])    



#todo
#---------
#ignore sub-folders
#confirm requestor
#undo feature    
#find out how to stop dos box showing in compiles prg
```

Comment: couldn't you just call `subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", folder_selected])`?

Comment: Hi Michael. I've tried that but it opens in steve\my documents.

Comment: yes, that does happen. I am confused as to why, though :/

Comment: _oh_, i see why!

Comment: even subprocess.Popen(["explorer"])   works the same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, your program is perfect, it's just that for some reason the wrong slashes were being used in the path, which python apparently could handle, but explorer.exe could not.
i ran your program, and printed out `folder_selected` and i got `C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/test`. which contains *forward slashes*, and windows paths use backslashes.
ao i would just replace `subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"])` to:   `subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", folder_selected.replace('/', '\\')])`
which will replace any forward slashes with backslashes, which explorer.exe should be able to handle.
hope this works :)
windows paths also cant have any kind of slash in them, so the user wont have a directory with any `/` in it, so `replace` should be fine

Comment: Thank you so much Michael, works perfectly. I doubt I would ever of worked that out, even though I printed out all the vars like you did :-)

Comment: you're welcome! you got to watch out for these kind of mistakes, where you have no idea whats going on and it turns out to be something silly :) have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

This problem caused by the difference between python/linux and windows representing paths. 
I printed the `folder_selected` and get:

```
C:/Users/name/Documents/Zevel
```

You need to add the following right after calling `askdirectory()`:

```
folder_selected = folder_selected.replace('/', '\\')
```

Making the path readable for windows, and now it looks like:

```
C:\Users\name\Documents\Zevel
```

Of course you need call `subprocess.Popen(["explorer", folder_selected])`
 and every thing will work.

Comment: Thanks Yanker, same answer as above and works beautifully. Now I need to find out how to ignore sub-folders as my little program renames them as well as the files lol