# Beginner:Python 3.66. Win7. How do I ignore sub-folders in this code?

Tags: python, windows, file, directory

Can anyone tell me how I can get the for loop at the end of this program
NOT to rename folders, only files? I'm at a loss on this one.

I'm assuming the command to use is if ***os.path.isdir(file)***
but I cant seem to get it to work no matter where I put it, same goes for ***os.path.isfile()***.

I'm still at the stage (my first week) where I am confused by most commands and functions, though I did dabble in ZX BASIC\AMOS and STOS in the 80s\90s so I have a rudimentary understanding of variables etc.

```
#FRenum-v.05
#renumbers a folder of files 01 onward preserving file extensions.
#steve Shambles. june 2018, my 2nd ever python program

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os
import os.path
import subprocess

#user selects directory
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()                             #stop tk window opening
folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory() #open file requestor

#change dir to folder selected by user,
os.chdir (folder_selected)

# read user selected dir   
files = os.listdir(folder_selected)

# inc is counter to keep track of what file we are working on
inc = 1 

for file in files:

    #store file extension in string file_ext
    file_ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

    # build new filename, starting with a "0" 
    #then value of inc then add file ext
    created_file=("0"+str(inc)+ file_ext)

    #if filename does not already exist then rename it
    if not os.path.exists(created_file):
        os.rename(file,created_file)
        #next one please, until done
        inc = inc+1 #add to counter

#Display contents of folder in explorer
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892257/beginner-opening-explorer-to-    show-folder-contents
subprocess.Popen(["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe", folder_selected.replace('/', '\\')])
#thanks to Michael for this line if code
```

Comment: You want to check if `os.path.isfile(file)` before you do anything. Skip the loop iteration if it is (you can use `continue` for this). Or filter the list you are iterating beforehand. That might be cleaner. What would *really* be cleaner is to use the `pathlib` instead of the `os.path` module.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Juanpa. I got it to ignore folders, but now it ignores all the files too :-) I'll have to try again in the morning when my mind is fresh, it's been a long day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## load the modules can add it at the beginning of the script

from os.path import join , isfile

## add this line before the loop:

files = [filenames for filenames in files if isfile(join(folder_selected, filenames))]

Comment: Thanks Gilad, I can't work out where this needs to go or if this will work inside my for loop.

Comment: place this line before your: "for file in files":

Comment: line 24, in <listcomp>
Comes up with this error Gilad:   files = [filenames for filenames in files if os.path.isfile(join(folder_selected, filenames))]
NameError: name 'join' is not defined

Comment: Forgot to import join - add the line: "from os.path import join

Comment: Aw yes,  it works perfect now. I will go try learn how that line of code actually works. Your help has been very much appreciated.